# GL_POSITION does not work

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, position, lighting

I want to add a Light source to my OpenGl code.
I have added following code to my init function...

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION,(50.0,0.0,0.0,1.0));
```

Moreover I have drawn a quad:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glNormal3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
glVertex3f(0.0,0.0,20.0);
glVertex3f(0.0,10.0,20.0);
glVertex3f(10.0,10.0,20.0);
glVertex3f(10.0,0.0,20.0);
glEnd();
```

But no matter what value I use for the Position,
the lighting doesn't change at all...

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Also, which C++ variant are you using where `(50.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)` evaluates to an array?  And even if it did, why aren't you using `glLightfv()`?

Comment: You are right!
I was such a fool...
But this is confusing me: If you have to use an array, why is there
glLightf and glLightfv???
What's the difference?

Comment: Some `pname` values like `GL_SPOT_CUTOFF` only require a single value and can use `glLightf()` (`param` argument is a single value) whereas things like `GL_POSITION` require *four* values and must use `glLightfv()` (`params` is a pointer type, suitable for passing in an array).

Answer (score 4):

```
glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION,(50.0,0.0,0.0,1.0));
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

`(50.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)` in this context will [evaluate to the last expression in the list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) (`1.0`).  Probably not what you want.

You need to use a real array and [`glLightfv()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glLight.xml) to specify light positions:

```
GLfloat pos[] = { 50.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0 };
glLightfv( GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, pos );
```